# Clear table values with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I need to have some sort of query that clears all values in a table but does not delete the column names.  For example:

```
r1 | r2 | r3
------------
v1 | v2 | v3
v4 | v5 | v6
```

The command should delete v1 through v6, yet leave the rows intact so that the table is empty.  The one question I've found that's closest to this mentions the `DELETE` query, but I'm pretty sure that using `DELETE` removes the column.

Comment: What are your desired results?  2 empty rows or no rows at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TRUNCATE table_name`. It will wipe all data but leave the structure intact.

Answer (score 0):

`UPDATE tbl SET v1 = null, v2 = null, v3 = null` will do what you ask without blanking the columns. Or you could just remove the display loop from php.

Answer (score 0):

`DELETE` doesn't remove columns.

What you might be looking for is :

```
UPDATE yourTable SET r1 = null, r2= null, r3 = null
```

It will fill all the rows of your table with `null` values.